# php login password not accepted

Tags: php, mysql

I am not able to log in using below code. So, here's my code:

```
    public function auth($login, $password)
    {
        $login = $this->db->real_escape_string($login);
        $tmp = $this->db->query("SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE login = '$login'");

        if (!$tmp->num_rows) {
            return false;
        }

        $userData = $tmp->fetch_assoc();
        var_dump($userData);
var_dump(sha1($password.'|'.$login));

        if ($userData[‘password’] == sha1($password.'|'.$login)) {

            return $userData['id'];

        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

And here's output from var dumps

```
array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "7" ["password"]=>
string(40) "e1c6d95317081ebddaea4cd1a061415c39dafb2b" }

string(40) "e1c6d95317081ebddaea4cd1a061415c39dafb2b"
```

How can I modify it, so I can log in?

Comment: Notice the curly quotes in `[‘password’]`?

Comment: And why not just use the new [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) with mysqli or PDO ?

Comment: Solved, I take it? If so, you can delete the question. If not, let us know.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just do..

```
$this->db->query('SELECT `id`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `login` = ? AND `password` = SHA1(CONCAT(?,"|",?))',array($login,$password,$login));
```